# RichTextBox highlight performance

Tags: wpf, performance, wpf-controls

I am working on application which highlight text in RichTextBox according to regex pattern. 
It works fine, except performance, even for small text (about 500 characters) it's hangs for some time which is visible to user.

Am I doing something wrong with FlowDocument? Can somebody point me out to the source of performance issue?

```
    public class RichTextBoxManager
{
    private readonly FlowDocument inputDocument;
    private TextPointer currentPosition;

    public RichTextBoxManager(FlowDocument inputDocument)
    {
        if (inputDocument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("inputDocument");
        }

        this.inputDocument = inputDocument;
        this.currentPosition = inputDocument.ContentStart;
    }

    public TextPointer CurrentPosition
    {
        get { return currentPosition; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            }
            if (value.CompareTo(inputDocument.ContentStart) < 0 ||
                value.CompareTo(inputDocument.ContentEnd) > 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
            }

            currentPosition = value;
        }
    }

    public TextRange Highlight(string regex)
    {
        TextRange allDoc = new TextRange(inputDocument.ContentStart, inputDocument.ContentEnd);
        allDoc.ClearAllProperties();
        currentPosition = inputDocument.ContentStart;

        TextRange textRange = GetTextRangeFromPosition(ref currentPosition, regex);
        return textRange;
    }

    public TextRange GetTextRangeFromPosition(ref TextPointer position,
                                              string regex)
    {
        TextRange textRange = null;
        while (position != null)
        {
            if (position.CompareTo(inputDocument.ContentEnd) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
            {
                String textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                var match = Regex.Match(textRun, regex);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index);
                    TextPointer nextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(regex.Length);
                    textRange = new TextRange(position, nextPointer);
                    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Yellow);
                    position = nextPointer;
                }
                else
                {
                    position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(textRun.Length);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            }
        }

        return textRange;
    }
}
```

to call it, I first create an instance in Initialize method

```
frm = new RichTextBoxManager(richTextBox1.Document);
```

and on textchange event for textbox (where I put regex) I call Highlight method

```
frm.Highlight(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way different approach but I use it with sub second response on files with 200,000 characters.

Since I am starting with text this may not be an option for you.

I index the text files for word position and the user can search on word.  I highlight the word(s) they searched on.

But I loop through the text to create the FlowDoc and highlight as I build the FlowDoc.  This FlowDoc has no formatting (other than the highlights).  So if you need to preserve formatting this would not work.

So my guess is the TextPointer is a lot of overhead.

But I learned a lot from your code as that was how I was going to try and highlight work but I could not make TextPointer work at all.

Maybe look at processing all matches in textRun rather then just the first and increment the position.